# UITableView add row below selected row

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I had a working tableview where I could double-tap a cell and it would add an 'action' cell below which had four buttons programmed on it. 
Today I added alphabetic sections to the tableview and a section index and I can no longer get this functionality to work. 
I've added a whole range of NSLogs to the code to try and find the problem and I can't, it seems to be trying to add a row in the same section and one row further down than the cell tapped, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Would anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
If anyone can shed any light on this I would be hugely appreciative. (And apologies if my code is cumbersome or hard to follow, I'm new to this so feel free to suggest what I can improve!)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
     {
     //I start with an array of objects, so I created two arrays; one containing the first letters of each Name, and a list of the number of objects that start with each of those names.
   nameIndex = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   nameIndexCount = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];   
    }

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     {
     return [nameIndex count];
      }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {
     if (self.actionRowIndexPath) {

     //Returns first letter of the section
     NSString *alphabet = [nameIndex objectAtIndex:section];

     //Returns the number of entries starting with that letter
    NSString *numberofRows = [nameIndexCount objectForKey:alphabet];
    int intNumberOfRows = ([numberofRows integerValue] + 1);

    return intNumberOfRows;
} else {

    NSString *alphabet = [nameIndex objectAtIndex:section];

    NSString *numberofRows = [nameIndexCount objectForKey:alphabet];
    int intNumberOfRows = [numberofRows integerValue];

    return intNumberOfRows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"newTableViewCell"];

    if (!cell) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"newTableViewCell"];
    }
    //Configure the cell
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LightGrey.png"];
    imageView.image = image;

    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.actionRowIndexPath]) {


        // Four UIButtons coded programmatically

    } else {


        Contact *p = [[[ContactStore sharedStore]allContacts]objectAtIndex:totalNumberOfRows];
        NSString *firstAndLastName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [p firstName], [p lastName]];
        indexPath = [self modelIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.backgroundView = imageView;
        //        [cell.imageView setImage:smallThumbnailImage];
        [cell.imageView setImage:[p thumbnail]];
        [[cell textLabel]setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [[cell textLabel]setText:firstAndLastName];
        [[cell detailTextLabel]setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [[cell detailTextLabel]setText:[p phoneNumber]];

        totalNumberOfRows = totalNumberOfRows + 1;
    }
    return cell;
}

    #pragma mark - Action Row Support

-(NSIndexPath *)modelIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (self.actionRowIndexPath == nil) {
        return indexPath;

    }

    if ([indexPath row] > [self.actionRowIndexPath row]) {
        return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([indexPath row] - 1) inSection:indexPath.section];

    }
    return indexPath;

}

 - (void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {


    NSLog(@"Double tap");

    CGPoint p = [recognizer locationInView:self.tableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];


    NSIndexPath *pathToDelete = self.actionRowIndexPath;

    _selectedIndexPath = [self modelIndexPath:_selectedIndexPath];

    //Is the user deselecting current row?
    if (_actionRowIndexPath) {
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:_selectedIndexPath animated:NO];
        self.selectedIndexPath = nil;
        self.actionRowIndexPath = nil;
    } else {
        //Selecting a new row
        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;

        self.actionRowIndexPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([indexPath row] + 1) inSection:[indexPath section]];
    }

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    if (pathToDelete) {
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:pathToDelete] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    }
    if (self.actionRowIndexPath) {
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.actionRowIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    }
    [self.tableView endUpdates];  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the **IndexPath** you need to get the **IndexPath.row** and **IndexPath.section** and accordingly you need to add the object into your array at the desired index. For example: if you double tap the 2nd row in the 1st section then you need to add the object at index 4 of the array corresponding to the 1st section and then reload table. The cell would be added to the 3rd index of the 1st section.

Comment: Hi Chirag, Thanks a lot for you response. Whereabouts did you think I should put that? I thought I have it in this line:       `self.actionRowIndexPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([indexPath row] + 1) inSection:[indexPath section]];`  which is then used in `[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.actionRowIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];`Should I put it somewhere else?

Comment: I am saying that you can perform this functionality in an easy way using the way i am telling you. You can put your code in `- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer` after getting IndexPath. You need to get the index and the Array the way i told you in the above answer. Once you get the array and the index for which you need to add the row. Just add the object in the Array at the desired index and reload the table. You will automatically get the row added below the row you tapped.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification, I'll see if I can try that way